# I'm trying to find a patern in the number compared to the dates

Tags: date, numbers, matching, relation

There is no fixed interval in the numbers based on the number of days between them. 
If you like numbercrunshing and patterns, here is a fun task.

*DATE FORMAT: DD.MM.YYYY*

1583017200000   02.03.2020
1582498800000   24.02.2020
1580598000000   03.02.2020
1575241200000   02.12.2019
1548457200000   28.01.2019
1425250800000   02.03.2015

**Purpose:** 
Create ***number-sequence*** based on ***date***.

Comment: It would help to know why those dates specifically

Comment: They just look like Unix seconds multiplied by 1000, and a one or two day offset.  But there's no code here, and this looks more appropriate for [puzzling.se].

Comment: The dates are generated by a website I collect data from. The numbersequence is used in a call to download files where it filters the relevant timeperiod.

Comment: The UNIX Seconds seems to work very well, thank you Toby  ;)